# opengl offscreen rendering in linux is slow

Tags: opengl, rendering, gpu, linux

My opengl application runs at about 110 fps. The moment I add off-screen rendering, it slows down to 15 fps. I am using frame buffer objects and glReadPixels to render off-screen. I have searched on net and found that GPU memory to CPU memory data transfer is slow and vice versa is fast. I have ATI Mobility Radeon™ X2300 with 128MB video memory.
So my questions are
1) Is there is way to increase VRAM to CPU ram data transfer speed?
2) Are there any GPUs in market optimized for better read speed?

Answer (score 4):

glReadPixels is going to naturally be slow. There really isn't any magic that will make this any faster than it is. I would suggest using glReadPixels to read your buffer to a PBO, and then read those PBOs asynchronously.

Depending on what you're trying to accomplish, [Render to Texture might be a better fit.](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-14-render-to-texture/)

Comment: `glReadPixels` is definitely your problem.  Don't use it unless you actually need the CPU to be able to perform logic based on the rendered image (for example, in order to convert it into a png to save it out as a screenshot).  If you're just going to push it straight back up to the GPU again for use in further drawing, then there are much faster ways to do that, such as the tutorial which Thebluefish linked to.

Comment: @TrevorPowell The final purpose of the application is to make movie using some video codec. I will need frames for that.

Comment: I would suggest creating a buffer of PBOs, say 4 PBOs in an array. Your game logic would use glReadPixels to populate those PBOs in order, and since this is done on the GPU side would be very fast. Make sure to use the GL_BGRA pixel format (otherwise you'll spend an eternity converting it) and use and an asynchronous thread to read the PBOs, preferably using glMapBuffer or glMapBufferRange.